# Mysql how to combine 2 update queries in 1

Tags: php, mysql

```
UPDATE `items` SET `score`=[value-1],`up_votes`=[value-2],`down_votes`=[value-3] WHERE `ID` = $id
UPDATE `items` SET `score`=[value-1],`up_votes`=[value-2],`down_votes`=[value-3] WHERE `ID` = $id
```

How can I combine these two queries when the IDs needs to be dynamic?
They are both coming from the table `items`.

Edit, the score ( can be + 10 or - 10) upvotes ( can be +1 or -1) and downvotes ( can be +1 or -1)

So they are also kind of dynamic, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: If the values are the same, you can just `OR` or `IN` in the condition. Are they?

Comment: Given that both queries are identical, `set score=value-2, down_votes=value-6, up_votes=value-4` would be "combination"

Comment: If the distinct ids have a relation between then you could use a OR on an IN clause, if not has to be done one by one

Answer (score 0):

Try this, $idlist is a comma separated list,

```
UPDATE `items` SET `score`=[value-1],`up_votes`=[value-2],`down_votes`=[value-3] WHERE `ID` in ($idlist)
```

Comment: Edit, the score ( can be + 10 or - 10) upvotes ( can be +1 or -1) and downvotes ( can be +1 or -1)

So they are also kind of dynamic, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

The the distinct id's are related by some condition, you can do:

```
UPDATE `items` SET `score`=[value-1],`up_votes`=[value-2],`down_votes`=[value-3] 
WHERE `ID` IN(SELECT ID FROM `items` WHERE SomeCondition)
```